# VC2010-SP1 Win7 32-bit - error C2338: CVarTypeInfo< char > cannot be compiled with /J or _CHAR_UNSIGNED flag enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, atl

I am getting following error on VC2010-SP1 Win7 32-bit. I tried for HotFix but it is no longer available here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982517. Can anyone help? Thanks

ClCompile:
  stdafx.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(1751): error C2338: CVarTypeInfo< char > cannot be compiled with /J or _CHAR_UNSIGNED flag enabled

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(1774): error C2338: CVarTypeInfo< char* > cannot be compiled with /J or _CHAR_UNSIGNED flag enabled

c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\odbcss.h(430): error C2371: 'WCHAR' : redefinition; different basic types
          c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(344) : see declaration of 'WCHAR'

Build FAILED.

Comment: As I am porting from earlier version of VS, so this is no solution. From menu select Project > Properties > C++ > Command Line and remove /J

Comment: As I am porting from earlier version of VS, so this is no solution. From menu select Project > Properties > General and set Character Set to Not Set instead of MBCS or Unicode

Answer (score 0):

> I tried for HotFix but it is no longer available here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982517.

It's still available, but listed as requiring a support call (as many KBs do by default). You can however ask for a download link by email.

Since you run SP1 of VS2010, KB 982517 points to [KB 2545588](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545588) for the fix. Following [How can you download a hotfix without contacting Microsoft?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mmcintyr/2008/09/02/how-can-you-download-a-hotfix-without-contacting-microsoft/) which still works nowadays, click...

http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2545588&kbln=en-us

...accept the terms, and provide a valid email where you'll receive the download link. Be prepared for a massive download to the tune of 270+ MB. If the hotfix doesn't fix it, or breaks anything else, don't expect much support from MS (since you just agreed to their terms in a previous step ;-)).

Comment: I tried URL for  How can you download a hotfix without contacting Microsoft? and response page is Sorry, the page you requested is not available.

Comment: I can confirm that the MS link now says `The page you were looking for is currently not available`. Wonder if `*currently*` means that it might be available next hour or tomorrow (it's Sunday night on the West coast of the US now, which is a popular time for server maintenance). FWIW I *did* try and requested the hotfix using that MS link before posting it, and I received the download link within minutes (on a @gmail address, if that matters). The file was named `435713_intl_i386_zip.exe` with a size of `283,691,424` bytes.

Comment: @Rafey It *was* a temporary glitch. The posted link works now, on Monday  at 19:30 UTC.

Comment: Thanks @dixv. 1. Resolved error C2338: CVarTypeInfo< char > cannot be compiled with /J or _CHAR_UNSIGNED flag enabled by setting Project Properties > C/C++ > Command Line > Additional Options (Removed /J)
2. Resolved error C2371: 'WCHAR' : redefinition; different basic types by setting Project Properties > General > Character Set (Set to Use Unicode Character Set)