# Visual Studio 2010 project not compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a visual studio project in 2010 installed on two different laptops, one with windows 7 and other one with windows 10. But the thing is that when i compile on windows 10 i get the errors:

```
Error   3   error C2338: CVarTypeInfo< char > cannot be compiled with /J or _CHAR_UNSIGNED flag enabled C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h   1751    1   PRJ_var
Error   4   error C2338: CVarTypeInfo< char* > cannot be compiled with /J or _CHAR_UNSIGNED flag enabled    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h   1774    1   PRJ_var
Error   5   error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'  D:\Novinsoft\NIS\scfa\NMAKE PRJ_var
Error   6   error MSB3073: The command "NMAKE /f PRJvar.mak /a" exited with code 2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets    43  6   PRJ_var
```

That's very weird because on windows 7 it compiles perfectly fine using Visual Studio 2010 Professional on both laptops. I have the same version of Visual Studio and same files/directories. Both laptops are using 64-bit OS.

Can anyone know what's the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps just compile without the `/J` option? The default to signed `char` is unfortunate, but since we have it I see no practical reason to force the compiler to behave differently. I'd use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` where I needed an unsigned byte type.

Comment: What does this question have to do with compiler construction (the making of a compiler)? Please don't just randomly add tags because they contain familiar words. Tags here have specific meanings. Read the description of the tag before using it to make sure it's appropriate. If you're not sure, leave it off and someone here will add it for you if needed.

Comment: My only thoughts are either that they aren't using the same version of VS2010 or that the build command is somehow different.  Can you check the versions and check that the full build command is the same?  If it is a version difference, then it might be related to the bug discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183598/vc2010-sp1-win7-32-bit-error-c2338-cvartypeinfo-char-cannot-be-compiled-wi).

Comment: Finally the problem was that some DLLs was not compatible with my current OS Windows 10 64-bit. That was the problem. Thanks.